# How to create python list at every new object detected

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am working on `python` `opencv` project where I am `detecting` and `tracking` person's movement in the frame. I am drawing a `line` from where the person enters in the frame and keeps drawing where ever the person moves in the frame and then finally stops when the person moves out of the frame. Below is the code:

```
centroid_dict = dict()
centroid_list = []
object_id_list = []

"""
SOME CODE
"""

objects = tracker.update(rects)
    for (objectID, bbox) in objects.items():
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = bbox
        x1 = int(x1)
        y1 = int(y1)
        x2 = int(x2)
        y2 = int(y2)
        cX = int((x1 + x2) / 2.0)
        cY = int((y1 + y2) / 2.0)
        cv2.circle(frame, (cX, cY), 4, (0, 255, 0), -1)

        centroid_list.append((cX, cY))
        centroid_dict[objectID] = centroid_list
        if objectID not in object_id_list:
            # This will run only once for the first time for every objectID
            start_pt = (cX, cY)
            end_pt = (cX, cY)
            cv2.line(frame, start_pt, end_pt, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            object_id_list.append(objectID)
            first_time = False
        else:
            l = len(centroid_list)
            for pt in range(len(centroid_dict[objectID])):
                if not pt + 1 == l:
                    start_pt = (centroid_dict[objectID][pt][0], centroid_dict[objectID][pt][1])
                    end_pt = (centroid_dict[objectID][pt+1][0], centroid_dict[objectID][pt+1][1])
                    cv2.line(frame, start_pt, end_pt, (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

In the above code, I am getting `objectID` and the `bounding box coordinates` of the person from `tracker.update(rects)`. Using the coordinates I am calculating the `cX` and `cY` which I use later to draw a line. I am appending all the `cX, cY` in  `centroid_list` which I am later adding it in `centroid_dict[objectID]`. This is working fine when the person is tracked. After the first person, when 2nd person comes in, it draws line from where the first person moved out of the frame and the main reason is that in the code, I am not clearing the `centroid_list` anywhere due to which it keeps holding the first person `cX` and `cY` and the 2nd person's `cX` and `cY` also due to which the line is drawn in wrong way.

The only solution is that I need to create separate list for every `objectID`. So that `cX` and `cY` are not mixed. I am not able to find a suitable solution for this. Can anyone please help me here. Thanks

**EDIT**

I am inferencing over a test video file. Here are few of the images to understand the scenario better

[image]

In the above image, we can see from where the lady enters and where she moved out of the frame. I have also marked the start and end point in the image. Now look at the below image where the 2nd lady comes in:

[image]

In above image, you can see that the 2nd lady has just entered but still for her the starting point is where the 1st lady entered previously and all the coordinates and the line drawn is from the 1st lady's coordinates. This happened because in our code `centroid_list` still contains the coordinates of the first lady so it actually starting drawing the line from where the 1st lady enters and thus makes no sense. Hope this scenario is much clear now.

Comment: A sample input and expected output would help.

Comment: @MayankPorwal I have added few picture to make it understand better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need `centroid_list` you can just use `centroid_dict`

you have to define `centroid_dict` as [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) before your `for` loop:

```
from collections import defaultdict
centroid_dict = defaultdict(list)
```

in your `for` loop:

```
centroid_dict[objectID].append((cX, cY))
```

to draw all the points just iterate on your `centroid_dict.values()`

Comment: No. Defining `centroid_list` in for loop will make it clear the previous coordinates of the person and thus no line will be drawn.

Comment: If you look at the code again, I am doing `centroid_dict[objectID] = centroid_list`. In your case, centroid list will contain the latest coordinates and not the previous coordinates and thus dict will only have the latest coordinates and not the previous coordinate. Just tried this also

Comment: sorry didnt get your comment, what do you mean by `you just need to use ```` `

Comment: This wont work also. Because the object id will remain same for 1st person, so every time we will have only one latest coordinate in dict and it wont save the previous coordinates. So the length will always be 1 and thus line cannot be drawn

Comment: I didnt knew about `centroid_dict = defaultdict(list)`. Thankyou